# How to pass Local<Function> as parameter?

Tags: c++, node.js, v8

I'm writing a C++ library for node.js, using v8. I'm on Windows, and I want to call an Win32 API function, `EnumWindows`, from my C++ code. `EnumWindows` takes a callback function and optional callback function parameter as parameters. My only goal with this C++ library is to expose `EnumWindows` to javascript-land, and be used like follows ...

```
mymodule.EnumWindows(function (id) { ... });
```

So, my C++ code looks like this ...

```
BOOL CALLBACK EnumWindowsProc(HWND hWnd, LPARAM lParam)
{
    // re-cast the Local<Function> and call it with hWnd
    return true;
}

Handle<Value> EnumWindows(const Arguments& args)
{
    HandleScope scope;

    // store callback function
    auto callback = Local<Function>::Cast(args[0]);

    // enum windows
    auto result = EnumWindows(EnumWindowsProc, callback);

    return scope.Close(Boolean::New(result == 1));
}
```

My question is how can I pass the `Local<Function`, in my `EnumWindows` wrapper, to the `EnumWindowsProc` callback function? The `EnumWindowsProc` is executed in the same thread.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could pass the address of the `callback`:

```
BOOL CALLBACK EnumWindowsProc(HWND hWnd, LPARAM lParam)
{
    Local<Function>& f = *reinterpret_cast<Local<Function>*>(lParam);

    // use f

    return true;
}

Handle<Value> EnumWindows(const Arguments& args)
{
    HandleScope scope;

    // store callback function
    auto callback = Local<Function>::Cast(args[0]);

    // enum windows
    auto result = EnumWindows(EnumWindowsProc,
                              reinterpret_cast<LPARAM>(&callback));

    return scope.Close(Boolean::New(result == 1));
}
```

Another option would be just collecting the handles to process them later:

```
BOOL CALLBACK EnumWindowsProc(HWND hWnd, LPARAM lParam)
{
    std::vector<HWND>* p = reinterpret_cast<std::vector<HWND>*>(lParam);
    p->push_back(hWnd);
    return true;
}

Handle<Value> EnumWindows(const Arguments& args)
{
    HandleScope scope;

    // store callback function
    auto callback = Local<Function>::Cast(args[0]);

    // enum windows
    std::vector<HWND> handles;
    auto result = EnumWindows(EnumWindowsProc,
                              reinterpret_cast<LPARAM>(&handles));

    // Do the calls...

    return scope.Close(Boolean::New(result == 1));
}
```